# Is there function to take the outer product of column vectors of a matrix?

Tags: julia

I need to take the outer products of each column vector of  a matrix with each column vector of another matrix

```
Example:

A=[1,2,3; 3,1,4; 4,1,3]
B=[2,1,3; 4,1,2; 3,2,1]

for each column of "A", I want to take it's outer product with each column of "B" and sum them all. I can do it in a loop but it is slow. Is there any other way of doing it fast?.
for example:

U=zeros(3,3)
for n=1:size(A,1)
    for m=1:size(B,1)
    U=U+A[:,n]'*B[:,m]
    end
end
```

Comment: What about the `'` in the line `U=U+A[:,n]'*B[:,m]`? I'm not familiar with julia, but that part looks wrong

Comment: @Samathingamajig, `A[:, n]' == transpose(A[:, n])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what the question wants:

```
function outsum1(A,B)
  U = zeros(size(A,1), size(B,1))
  for n=1:size(A,1)   # independent loops n and m
    for m=1:size(B,1)
      U = U + A[:,n]*B[:,m]'  # transpose the second for outer product?
    end
  end
  U
end
A = [1 2 3; 3 1 4; 4 1 3];  # can't mix , (vectors) and ; / space (concatenation)
B = [2 1 3; 4 1 2; 3 2 1]
outsum1(A,B) == [36 42 36; 48 56 48; 48 56 48]
```

If so, there are ways that you can make this function more efficient (e.g. `@views U .= U .+ A[:,n] .* B[:,m]'`). But the most important one is probably to notice that these loops don't have to be nested. In index notation:

```
U[i,j] = sum_m,n A[i,n] * B[j,m]
       = (sum_n A[i,n]) * (sum_m B[j,m])
```

The first form has 4 nested loops, the second has only 2. So this function will be much faster for large `A`, by roughly a factor `length(A)`:

```
outsum2(A,B) = sum(A, dims=2) .* sum(B, dims=2)'
outsum2(A,B) == [36 42 36; 48 56 48; 48 56 48]  # same answer
```

Another answer interprets "outer products of each column vector of a matrix with each column vector of another" to mean one sum over columns, not two. That is very different, and in index notation it reads:

```
U[i,j] = sum_n A[i,n] * B[j,n]
```

This is matrix multiplication, `U = A * B'`.

Comment: thanks! @mcabbott for the answer it works and  really liked your trick/method :)